# hypermesh will stop working when i booted it,,what's wrong with it?

Tags: altair

Several days ago , hypermesh can still work ,but  yesterday, when I click the "hypermesh desktop" button on my desktop,there is no response. and if I click the "hypermesh" (not "hypermesh desktop") in start menu , I can boot it ,but a tough problem with no hint appeared.I put the error picture bellow:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nc9l.png)
Does anyone has met the same problem? and how can I fixed it ,I don't want to reinstall hypermesh.

Comment: the error message is in Chinese ,In English is :Altair Hyperworks stopped working , As there is a problem in the software ,the application stopped working. Windows will close the application ,and will inform you when usable solution finded.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your HM's license sever manage is blocked by the anti-virus software, u must check before booting HM.

Answer (score 0):

According to the  message,  it  is  very  difficult  to diagnoise  the  problem.  In  my  opinion,  license  server  is most probably  not  started  properly. Two  options  are listed  as following:

(1) You  should  check  the  status  of hm's license  server  from your  computer`s  task  manager. 
(2) Check  the  expire  date  of  hm's  license.  If  the  license  is expired,  you  can  try  the  way  to change  your  computer's system  date.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a friend having this problem. I didn't know why, but we discovered it would launch from the Start menu located on one monitor but hang-up like yours did if we launched from an Explorer window on the other monitor. Really. Maybe because of Tc or a license tied to a Primary Display.
I have no idea but it was 100% fixed when launching from the Primary monitor, even if only dragging the File Explorer window to the Primary monitor it would work.
One more thing the Nvidia GTX 1080 would not work if calling
"C:\Program Files\Altair\2019\hw\bin\win64\hw.exe" /clientconfig hwfepre.dat

but the [apparently] OpenGL version works with:

"C:\Program Files\Altair\2019\hm\bin\win64\hmopengl.exe"

The programs look identical with separate shortcuts in the shortcut group installed on Start menu. I am assuming HyperMesh and Hyperworks are the same then... but there was also an updated Hyperworks interface that DID work with the Nvidia GTX1080:

"C:\Program Files\Altair\2019\hwx\bin\win64\runhwx.exe" -client HyperWorksDesktop -plugin HyperworksGeneral -profile HyperworksGeneral -v "HyperWorks 2019.1" -l en -sf plugins/hwd/resources/splashHyperWorks.png -b1

I know nothing about the program... just that we figured out how to launch it. Good Luck.